keeping one occurance of repeated elements according to the value of 2nd column in R
I am merging 2 files using the following code in R:
file1 <- read.csv("file1.csv")
file2 <- read.csv("file2.csv")


merged_data <- file1 %>%
    merge(file2, by = "target_id") %>%
    select(gene_name, tpm)

and here is a part of resulting output:
gene_name   tpm
DDX11L1 4.41094e-01
DDX11L1 0.00000e+00
WASH7P  1.35118e+01
OR4G4P  0.00000e+00
OR4G11P 0.00000e+00
OR4F5   0.00000e+00
RP11-34P13.15   2.24436e+00
RP11-34P13.15   1.61390e+01
RP11-34P13.15   5.28307e+00
AP006222.1  4.40610e-01
RP4-669L17.8    5.32640e+00
CICP7   2.49001e-04
WBP1LP7 0.00000e+00
RP4-669L17.1    1.11826e+00
MTND1P23    1.86004e+01
MTND1P23    9.26279e+01

the first column (gene_name) has repeated elements. I would like to keep only keep only one repeat of each element in the first column if that repeat has the highest number in the 2nd column (tpm) among the repeat of that elements. for the above example, the expected output looks like this:
gene_name   tpm
DDX11L1 4.41094e-01
WASH7P  1.35118e+01
OR4G4P  0.00000e+00
OR4G11P 0.00000e+00
OR4F5   0.00000e+00
RP11-34P13.15   5.28307e+00
AP006222.1  4.40610e-01
RP4-669L17.8    5.32640e+00
CICP7   2.49001e-04
WBP1LP7 0.00000e+00
RP4-669L17.1    1.11826e+00
MTND1P23    9.26279e+01

how can I change the above code to et the expected output?

I'm curious, was there something lacking in my answer as this question has yet to be "answered"?

This is easely done using dplyr package by grouping the dataframe by gene_name and then using slice_max() to select for each gene_name the row with the highest tpm value.
#load packages 
library(dplyr)

#creata sample data
data <- data.frame(
      gene_name = c("DDX11L1", "DDX11L1", "WASH7P", "OR4G4P", "OR4G11P", "OR4F5", 
                    "RP11-34P13.15", "RP11-34P13.15", "RP11-34P13.15", "AP006222.1", 
                    "RP4-669L17.8", "CICP7", "WBP1LP7", "RP4-669L17.1", 
                    "MTND1P23", "MTND1P23"),
      tpm = c(4.41094e-01, 0.00000e+00, 1.35118e+01, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 
              0.00000e+00, 2.24436e+00, 1.61390e+01, 5.28307e+00, 4.40610e-01, 
              5.32640e+00, 2.49001e-04, 0.00000e+00, 1.11826e+00, 1.86004e+01, 
              9.26279e+01)
    )

#keep row with max tpm by gene_name group
data <- data %>%
  group_by(gene_name) %>% 
  slice_max(tpm)

Output
   gene_name           tpm
   <chr>             <dbl>
 1 AP006222.1     0.441   
 2 CICP7          0.000249
 3 DDX11L1        0.441   
 4 MTND1P23      92.6     
 5 OR4F5          0       
 6 OR4G11P        0       
 7 OR4G4P         0       
 8 RP11-34P13.15 16.1     
 9 RP4-669L17.1   1.12    
10 RP4-669L17.8   5.33    
11 WASH7P        13.5     
12 WBP1LP7        0 


file1 <- read.csv("file1.csv")
file2 <- read.csv("file2.csv")


merged_data <- file1 %>%
merge(file2, by = "target_id") %>%
group_by(gene_name) %>%
filter(tpm == max(tpm)) %>%
select(gene_name, tpm)

merged_data = ungroup(merged_data)

